# c# aspx connect to postgresql with Npgsql

Tags: asp.net, web-config, npgsql

I have the annoying task of hooking a c# aspx page up to postgresql with Npgsql.

The problem that i have is that when i try to import Npgsql, i get the following aspx error message returned:

> CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Npgsql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have a javascript function that calls the aspx page below to get data from the db:

```
<%@ language="C#"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="Npgsql" %>
<%

  // PostgeSQL-style connection string
  string connstring = String.Format("Server=localhost;Port=5432;UID=posgres;Password=pass;Database=postgres_db;";
  NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);      
  conn.Open();
%>
```

Im assuming i need to set it up in my web.config, but i cannot for the life of me it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the Npgsql.dll that is not being references. You only import the Namespace.

It's not best practice to hack SQL into a ASP.NET document... The solution would be adding the DLL to the web.config file:

```
 ...
  <system.web>         
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">                              
      <assemblies> 
        <add assembly="Npgsql, Version=2.0.11.93, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />  
  ...
```

But I recommend to create a class library project or at least a Web Application project using Visual Studio (Express version is FREE). Then right click on the directory named references and add the DLL there. Why? N-Tier (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture): better organization of code by it's intent. Easier to find errors and change/maintain code...

Comment: I thought that i would need to add something in the web.conf, ill give your code a try, however, if i just have a few aspx files (not part of a web application project) and im calling in the assemblies in the web.conf file, how would i access that from my aspx files? just 'import' and use it the way i have in my code, or do i need to so something fancy?

Comment: Oh darn, just got a chance to test this out now, and im getting an error when the page loads

'Could not load file or assembly 'Npgsql, Version=2.0.11.93, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: Of course you need to set the exact version/public key of YOUR Npgsql.dll